# Bootstrap 4 responsive table header alignment issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I am using the classes **d-none** and **d-md-block** on a responsive table to hide specific columns on smaller resolutions.  It works great with one exception.   The columns that use these classes are slightly out of alignment with the other columns.  When inspecting the column I can't find any rules that might be causing this.

It seems like the padding or the margin for these columns might be off by a couple pixels but I can't for the life of me pin it down.  The padding and margin appears to be the same as the non-responsive columns.  Here is an example of the issue:
[image]

You can see the code at https://bitmagi.com/ and than clicking on the "Trades/Add Trade" menu.

Comment: I think you need to use the table show and hide classes. You change the element display when you set it to display block as d-md-block does. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by `d-md-block`. What that does is make the table cell turn into a block element, which is not the default behaviour of `<th>`. Hence the spacing issue.

Solution: Use `d-md-table-cell` instead of `d-md-block`

Working Eg:

```
<th class="d-none d-md-table-cell" style="text-align: right;">Exchange</th>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I wrestled with this for too long!  I owe you a beer!